# Is there a way to pass Webpack the code to be bundled from a code string variable?

Tags: node.js, webpack, babeljs

I am trying to transpile and bundle my React code in a node script. I was able to store the transpiled code in a variable but I am not able to find a way to pass this to the webpack node interface.

Another level of complexity here would be that since I have multiple files to bundle and I'm not sure how I can serve these multiple files to webpack.

```
babelOptions = {
    presets : ['@babel/preset-env','@babel/preset-react']
};
const fs = require('fs');
const targetFiles = fs.readdirSync('./src');
const code ={};
const babel = require('@babel/core');
for(const file of targetFiles){
    code[file] = babel.transformFileSync('./src/'+file,babelOptions).code;
}
const webpack = require('webpack');
//Bundling Happens now
```

I'm sure that there are much better command-line solutions to this but I'm interested in doing this in a node script. I'm positive that this can be done since I believe that webpack with the babel-loader takes the code from memory too.

Any non-CLI solutions are welcome

Comment: Why do you not configure webpack to apply the babel transform and just pass the entry file to webpack?

Comment: There is no specific reason. I would just like to understand everything that happens and therefore instead of letting webpack and babel interact directly, I want to configure and make everything work manually

Comment: This is probably a lot more difficult (if it's even possible) because the majority of the work that webpack is doing is resolving dependencies. Starting at a file it determines all its dependencies, and their dependencies and so on. As part of this process it transforms the files according to its configuration. It almost seems like you want to completely bypass this process, but then why use webpack at all? If you still want webpack to perform dependency resolution, I don't think you can say "start at this file but instead of transforming it yourself, use this ready made version instead".